# how to identify relations between continous and categorical(binary) variables?

Tags: correlation

Basically, I have two timestamped  datasets.I DID spend lot of time searching for an answer without anything convincing.

The first dataset is of continuous variables. It is under this format:

```
Timestamp            P1     P2    P3     P4
14:47 15/09/2016     340     364   329    0.2
15:18 15/09/2016     366      365   301   0.5
```

The other is a history of signifcant events and their timestamps:

```
Timestamp                    Event
14:47:24 15/09/2016         E1,E3
14:48:15 15/09/2016         E2
15:37:02 15/09/2016         E5
```

What I want to do is to identify  implicit relations between events appearance and changes in the variables values.For this purpose, I thought of using  [the correlation ration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio) but I am not sure it is suited for this kind of problems .

Do you know other measures that are suitable for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single dataset out of this, by joining both the datasets on the time. Now build a multi-class logistic/machine learning model to understand the impact of the variables p1-p4(independent variables) on the event type(target)